# How to know when an [input] is set in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I wonder is there any event.... to check when an input is set in the Angular2 Component. Below is my sample code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sample-list',
  inputs: ['size']
})
```

Obviously,  in some template, this component is used as follow:

```
<sample-list [size]="1000"></sample-list>
```

Is there anyway (event...) I can observe when size is set to 1000?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a setter property from within your component:

```
@Input() set size(n:number) {
    this._size = n;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Implement

```
ngOnChanges(changes) {
  // 
}
```

which is called when inputs are changes. This isn't called when an input is changed by direct access (`size = 50`), only when an bound value changed `[size]="aFieldWithAChangingValue"`